# Gcloud update broke my app -- GCP Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I just upgraded GCloud and now I can't start my dev-env.

gcloud --version

- Google Cloud SDK 238.0.0
- app-engine-go
- app-engine-python 1.9.84
- app-engine-python-extras 1.9.74 beta 2019.02.22
- bq 2.0.42
- cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
- core 2019.03.08
- gsutil 4.37

I don't understand these errors ... all feedback appreciated!

```
WARNING  2019-03-13 20:38:17,348 multistore_file.py:62] The oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file module has been deprecated and will be removed in the next release of oauth2client. Please migrate to multiprocess_file_storage.
ERROR    2019-03-13 20:38:17,586 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/svcAdminApi/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import endpoints as google_cloud_endpoints
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/endpoints/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .apiserving import *
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/endpoints/apiserving.py", line 77, in <module>
    from . import endpoints_dispatcher
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/endpoints/endpoints_dispatcher.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in <module>
    class Environment:
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in Environment
    self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 190, in get_supported_platform
    plat = get_build_platform()
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 398, in get_build_platform
    version = _macosx_vers()
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/dev/TouchstoneMicroservices/lib/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 369, in _macosx_vers
    version = platform.mac_ver()[0]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 764, in mac_ver
    info = _mac_ver_xml()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 741, in _mac_ver_xml
    pl = plistlib.readPlist(fn)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 75, in readPlist
    pathOrFile = open(pathOrFile)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/stubs.py", line 283, in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
INFO     2019-03-13 20:38:17,610 module.py:861] adminapi: "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: "gcloud components restore"
got me running again but I'm certain I can't live long that way so please tell me what to change

Comment: While I'm at it, I should call your attention to a docs inconsistency ... most recent feedback on GCP groups & other docs says to use virtualenv but the cloudendpoints/endpoints-python/ library specifically says you must use /lib vendoring

Comment: virtualenv is for running on your development machine.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, I understand that venv is for local/dev use.   This problem IS happening on my local/dev environment.  So I'm clearly not following your point?  Please clarify.

Comment: You mentioned virtualenv and /lib in your comment. I was joint pointing out that virtualenv is for your development environment. /lib is in your deployment configuration file.

Comment: Yes, I do understand all of that but as my comment says:
endpoints-python/ library docs specifically says it is NOT COMPATIBLE with venv
So I was pointing out that the general advice to use venv for local development may be inaccurate for people using that library

now that we've cleared that up, do you have any tips for what broke i the latest GCloud??

Comment: Also running into the same issue with my app trying to use the latest gcloud version (bumped)

Answer (score 2):

Google was notified about this case: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132240370

Please, star this issue if you also have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

reading you original questions,the first error indicates that the oauth2client.contrib.multistore_file module has been deprecated and is nos longer supported, so you have to replace it, in the link[1] you can find the reason why it has been deprecated and what is the replacement.

[1]https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html

Answer (score 0):

This now appears to be fixed as of Google Cloud SDK 253.0.0.

Run `gcloud components update` and you should be good to go!